# I am having problem about from up to the bottom line in python

Tags: python

[This is the current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPm2D.png)

[This is the one I am trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dtHo.png)

**i have tried a lot of solutions but couldn't do it.
code of the program I am trying to do
i would appreciate if someone helps me <3**

`

```
import random 


class TicTacToe:

    def __init__(self):
        self.board = []

    def create_board(self):
        for i in range(3):
            row = []
            for j in range(3):
                row.append('-')
            self.board.append(row)
            
                
            
            

    def get_random_first_player(self):
        return random.randint(0, 1)

    def fix_spot(self, row, col, player):
        self.board[row][col] = player

    def is_player_win(self, player):
        win = None

        n = len(self.board)

        # checking rows
        for i in range(n):
            win = True
            for j in range(n):
                if self.board[i][j] != player:
                    win = False
                    break
            if win:
                return win

        # checking columns
        for i in range(n):
            win = True
            for j in range(n):
                if self.board[j][i] != player:
                    win = False
                    break
            if win:
                return win

        # checking diagonals
        win = True
        for i in range(n):
            if self.board[i][i] != player:
                win = False
                break
        if win:
            return win

        win = True
        for i in range(n):
            if self.board[i][n - 1 - i] != player:
                win = False
                break
        if win:
            return win
        return False

        for row in self.board:
            for item in row:
                if item == '-':
                    return False
        return True

    def is_board_filled(self):
        for row in self.board:
            for item in row:
                if item == '-':
                    return False
        return True

    def swap_player_turn(self, player):
        return 'X' if player == 'O' else 'O'

    def show_board(self):
        for row in self.board:
            for item in row:
                print(item, end=" ")
            print()

    def start(self):
        self.create_board()

        player = 'X' if self.get_random_first_player() == 1 else 'O'
        while True:
            print(f"Player {player} turn")
            print("1 2 3")
            print("-----")
            
            self.show_board()

            # taking user input
            row, col = list(
                map(int, input("Enter row and column numbers: ").split()))
            print()
            

            # fixing the spot
            self.fix_spot(row - 1, col - 1, player)

            # checking whether current player is won or not
            if self.is_player_win(player):
                print(f"Player {player} wins the game!")
                break

            # checking whether the game is draw or not
            if self.is_board_filled():
                print("Match Draw!")
                break

            # swapping the turn
            player = self.swap_player_turn(player)

        # showing the final view of board
        print()
        self.show_board()


# starting the game
tic_tac_toe = TicTacToe()
tic_tac_toe.start()
```

`

I mentioned it above this text

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly define your table format:

```
BOARD = """   1 2 3
--------
A| - - - 
B| - - -
C| - - -"""
```

And then update it the following way:

```
BOARD = """   1 2 3
--------
A| - - - 
B| - - -
C| - - -"""
COORDINATES = {'A1': 21, 'A2': 23, 'A3': 25,
               'B1': 31, 'B2': 33, 'B3': 35,
               'C1': 40, 'C2': 42, 'C3': 44}

player = 'O'
while True:
    print(f'Player {player} turn')
    print(BOARD)
    while True:
        action = input('Enter row and column numbers (e.g. "B2"): ')
        try:
            index = COORDINATES[action]
            BOARD = BOARD[:index] + player + BOARD[index + 1:]
            break
        except KeyError:
            print(f'Incorrect row and column: "{action}". Please enter correct values.')
    player = 'O' if player == 'X' else 'X'
```

Output:

```
Player O turn
   1 2 3
--------
A| - - - 
B| - - -
C| - - -
Enter row and column numbers (e.g. "B2"): A1
Player X turn
   1 2 3
--------
A| O - - 
B| - - -
C| - - -
Enter row and column numbers (e.g. "B2"): B2
Player O turn
   1 2 3
--------
A| O - - 
B| - X -
C| - - -
```